# Prove the existence of $\sqrt b$ for any real number $b\geq 0.$

Tags: real-analysis, proof-explanation

I was recently going through a proof of the result  that:

"Prove the existence of $\sqrt b$ for any real number $b\geq 0.$"

The proof I encountered was:

Define the set $T = \{t\in\Bbb R : t^2 < b\}$ and let $\alpha =\sup T$ which we know exists because $T$ is non-empty (it contains $0$) and bounded above. We’ll show $\alpha^2= b$ by ruling out the possibilities  $\alpha^2\lt b$ and  $\alpha^2\gt b.$

First assume $\alpha^2\lt b$ and observe, $(\alpha+\frac 1n)^2= \alpha^2+\frac 1{n^2}+2\frac{\alpha}{n}\lt \alpha^2+\frac 1{n}+2\frac{\alpha}{n}.$  From  Archimedian Property, we choose $n_0$ large enough so that $\frac{1}{n_0}\lt\frac{b-\alpha^2}{2\alpha+1}.$ This implies $\frac{2{\alpha} + 1}{n_0} < b-\alpha^2$, and consequently that $(\alpha+\frac 1n_0)^2\lt b.$

Thus, $\alpha+\frac1{n_0}\gt \alpha,$ contradicting the fact that $\alpha$ is an upper bound for $T.$

We conclude that $\alpha ^2< b$ cannot happen.

Now, let’s assume $\alpha^2\gt b.$ This time, we have, $(\alpha-\frac 1n)^2= \alpha^2+\frac 1{n^2}-2\frac{\alpha}{n}\gt \alpha^2-2\frac{\alpha}{n}.$
This time pick $n_0$ large enough so that $\frac{1}{n_0}\lt\frac{\alpha^2-b}{2\alpha+1}.$

With this choice of $n_0,$ we have  $(\alpha-\frac 1{n_0})^2\gt b.$

This means $\alpha-\frac 1{n_0}$ is an upper bound for $T.$ But then $(\alpha-\frac 1{n_0})\lt \alpha = \sup T,$ which leads to a contradiction because all upper bounds of $T$ should be greater than
or equal to the supremum $\alpha.$ Thus, $\alpha^2 > b$ is not a possibility and we are left with $\alpha^2 =b$ as desired.

---

However, I dont understand  how they are saying, "This means $\alpha-\frac 1{n_0}$ is an upper bound for $T$". I feel this needs more clarity. This is because, any real number $x\in \Bbb R$ such that $x^2\gt b,$ implies $x\notin T,$ but this does not nnecessarily, mean that $x$ is  a upper bound of $T.$ For example, if $b=2,$ then $-\sqrt 3\notin T,$ and $(-\sqrt 3)^2=3\gt 2,$ But this does not  mean that $-\sqrt 3$ is an upper bound of $T,$ for $1\in T$ and $-\sqrt 3\lt 1.$ So, I feel that we can't really, assert  that $(\alpha-\frac 1{n_0})$ is an upper bound  of $T.$
Any possible explanation regarding  this issue would be really very helpful.

Comment: Do you see that for any $t\in T, t\lt \alpha -\frac 1{n_0}?$

Comment: @AnneBauval How do you claim that the inequality, "$\frac1{n_0}\le\frac{\alpha^2-b}{2\alpha}<\alpha$ " holds true ?

Comment: @Koro I am sorry, but I don't get what are you trying to imply?

Comment: @AnneBauval Ok, but how do you know that $\alpha\gt 0$ ? Am I missing something?

Comment: @AnneBauval If $b=0$, then $t\in T$ only if, $t^2\lt 0$. But $t\in R$ so, $t^2\geq 0$. Thus, $b\neq 0.$ So, $b>0$. This means $0^2\lt b$ and hence, $0\in T$ due to which, $\alpha\geq 0$ and from our assumption $\alpha^2\gt 0$ so, $\alpha\neq 0$ and thus, $\alpha\gt 0.$ I think this should be the logic. But then again, this means our proof do not work, if $b=0$ ?

Comment: @AnneBauval But we don't need this proof to show $0\in\Bbb R$ as $0\in \Bbb Q$ . Am I correctly judging the situation?

Comment: @AnneBauval Will you please considering adding your comments as an answer, for then I will be glad to accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your definition of $T$ is not correct. It should be $T=\{t∈R:t^2\le b\}$ since they did not exclude $b=0$ and they are saying that $T$ contains $0$.

As a consequence, $\alpha\ge0.$

"Now, let’s assume $\alpha^2\gt b.$" Then, $\frac1{n_0}\le\frac{\alpha^2-b}{2\alpha+1}$ by choice of $n_0,$ and $\frac{\alpha^2-b}{2\alpha+1}\le\alpha$ because $\alpha\ge0$ and $b\ge0.$ Therefore,
$$\alpha-\frac1{n_0}\ge0.$$

"$(\alpha-\frac 1{n_0})^2\gt b.$ This means $\alpha-\frac 1{n_0}$ is an upper bound for $T.$" Indeed,
$$\forall t\in T\quad\alpha-\frac 1{n_0}\ge t$$ because $\alpha-\frac1{n_0}\ge0$ and:

- either $t\le0$ and then the conclusion is obvious,
- or $t>0$ and then, the conclusion follows from $(\alpha-\frac 1{n_0})^2\gt b\ge t^2.$

Answer (score 1):

First of all we should observe that we must treat the case $b = 0$ separately (the assertion is trivially true in this case). In fact, for $b = 0$ the set $T$ is empty and the argument does not work.

For $b > 0$ the set $T$ is nonempty. For $b \le 1$ it is bounded above by $1$ and for $b > 1$ it is bounded above by $b$. Note that $\alpha =  \sup T \ge 0$ since $0 \in T$.

Note that in the first step $\alpha^2 < b$ was ruled out which automatically implies that $\alpha > 0$.

> "This means $\alpha-\frac 1{n_0}$ is an upper bound for $T$". I feel this needs more clarity.

You are right, but it is very easy to see that $\alpha-\frac 1{n_0}$ is an upper bound for $T$. For $t \in T$ we have $t^2 < b < (\alpha-\frac 1{n_0})^2$. This implies $t < \alpha-\frac 1{n_0}$.

Just for the sake of completeness let us prove it and assume that $\alpha-\frac 1{n_0} \le t$. Equality is impossible because then $(\alpha-\frac 1{n_0})^2 = t^2 < b$. Thus $\alpha-\frac 1{n_0} < t$. But since $\alpha > 0$ and $n_0$ is "big", we have $0 < \alpha-\frac 1{n_0} < t$. We conclude
$$(\alpha-\frac 1{n_0})^2 = (\alpha-\frac 1{n_0}) \cdot (\alpha-\frac 1{n_0}) < (\alpha-\frac 1{n_0}) \cdot t < t \cdot t = t^2 < b$$
which is a contradiction.